# Blend [alphablend] with [alphablending]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[alphablend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphablend) has no wiki, no followers, and 13 questions. [alphablending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphablending), on the other hand, has a wiki excerpt, 2 followers, and 360 questions. Let's merge the former into the latter and maybe synonymize them.

Comment: There are lots of [tag:blend] questions related to blending, not MS Blend tool

Comment: There are also [tag:blending] and [tag:color-blending]

Comment: @VadimKotov: Ask a new question.